Return multiple selected cells from excel into python via xlwings
I am trying to figure out how to pass several selected cells from excel into python via xlwings on macOS.  I found code that passes cell notation but not all of the values.
For example:  In my worksheet, I selected cells D8, D12, D18, and D21 having values of cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4
Code:
  wb   = xw.Book.caller()
  dbg = wb.sheets['debug']

  selected_range = wb.selection

  Print results in my debug worksheet

  dbg.range((1, 1)).value = selected_range.address

This is what gets printed:  $D$8,$D$12,$D$18,$D$21
What I am looking for are the actual values of the cells.
I tried another example:
  cellRange = wb.app.selection
  rowNum = cellRange.row
  colNum = cellRange.column
  dbg.range((2, 1)).value = len(cellRange), rowNum, colNum

This is what printed
$D$8,$D$12,$D$18,$D$21  1, 8, 4
The 1, 8, 4 corresponds to
cellRange = 1
rowNum = 8
colNum = 4

This says $D$8,$D$12,$D$18,$D$21 is one object and rowNum/colNum point to the first cell of the 4 I selected.
What am I missing?  I want to return the values into my code to act on.
Thanks
Dan

You have to loop. You can't get the values of a multi-area range otherwise.

Loop thru what?  The cell coordinates are all returned as one string, not a list.  I could certainly use the coordinates to build code to access the values but I was hoping xlwings provided some easier solution.

Loop through cellRange.Areas

   x=0
   for item in cellRange.Area:
      dbg.range((x, 1)).value = item
      x+=1.  ```  AttributeError: 'Range' object has no attribute 'Areas'

Not sure what you mean.  Can you please prove a code sample?  Thanks

My mistake. Areas would be accessed through the underlying pywin32 native object. If you're on macOS, it'd be an appscript native object, which I'm not familiar with.

did you try .value instead of .address? selected_range.value? See documentation for Range.value

As suggested you would need loop the addresses or something similar.
So you select the cells D8, D12, D18, and D21 then have the Python code split the range address and get the value for each.
def main():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    dbg = wb.sheets['debug']

    selected_range = wb.selection

    # Values list 
    cell_values = [dbg[cell].value for cell in selected_range.address.split(',')]

    # Print results in my debug worksheet
    dbg.range((1, 1)).value = cell_values




One typo but it worked as expected.  Thank you very much.  Typo  for my use case 'dbg[cell].value' should be 'ws[cell].value' but it works!
